# Calendar Tag Full Day of the Month

Tags: date, calendar, date-format, calendar-events

EE 5.2.2

Quite a simple question: In the EE calendar tag, instead of showing `{day_number}`, I'd like something like `{day_of_week}`. So rather than showing '5' I want my calendar to show 'Thursday, 5' -- so the day of the week and the number as well.

Am I missing something from [the docs](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/channels/calendar.html)? I've tried doing `{date format="{format}"}` with no luck. This seems like it would be a common feature.

**EDIT** I ended up solving this issue using php but it's probably still useful to have the answer if someone knows how to do with with the calendar tag functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The information you need is in the documentation - [here](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/templates/date-variable-formatting.html#date-variable-formatting).

The tag parameter is pretty simple to use - I think you would end up with something like this:

`{date_variable format="%l, %j %F %Y"}`

which would give an output something like **Thursday, 5 January 2019**

HTH

Comment: I'm not sure how this would work with the issue I was having unless the `{date_variable}` can accept parameters to translate integers into days like the `date()` function in php. The EE `{calendar}` tag does a great job for most things, but within each cell it seems to only have a `{day_number}` option, whereas I'm looking for a day number AND a day of the week for each cell/day within the calendar. What you're suggesting would put whatever date format TODAY is within every calendar cell, would it not?

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is - the `{calendar}` tag has a variable called `{date}` that can accept standard date formatting - see docus here https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/channels/calendar.html#date  - So presumably I'm still not getting what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: Well, I can't explain why but using the `{date}` tag within the `{calendar]` breaks it. :/